# My app crashes when using fragment transaction animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, fatal-error, crash-reports

Sometimes, not always, on some old devices my app crashes when I use animation for fragment transaction, and I get this error :

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

If I don't use animation the problem goes away.
Here is my code :

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left_s, R.anim.slide_out_right_s,R.anim.slide_in_right_s,R.anim.slide_out_left_s);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment,tag).addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here is my slide_in_left_s.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
   <translate android:duration="300" android:fromXDelta="-100%" 
   android:toXDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`
because you are you using support fragment .

that's why it crashes on old devices.

Comment: I changed it to getSupportFragmentManager() but the problem is still on. As I mentioned the error is Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)  and i think there is something wrong with memory or something like this